# Filter out search results with low quality images

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

Attempting to filter out search results with low quality images in a table. I have run it in the browser console and receive the error something is undefined, but as to what, I am unaware of.

```js
var imgTag = document.querySelectorAll('img > center');
var imgSize = ['Low Quality', 'Medium Quality'];
for (i = 0; i < imgTag.length; ++i) {
  var imgElm = imgTag[i];
  var indic = false;
  for (j = 0; j < imgSize.length; ++j) {
    var size = imgSize[j];
    if (imgElm.getAttribute("alt").match(size)) {
      indic = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (indic) {
    var p = imgElm.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    p.setAttribute("style", "display:none;")
  }
}
```

Here is a minimal working example of the html the script is attempting to work for.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Minimal Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1px">
      <td align="center" valig="top">
            <div class="avatar" style="height: 140px; width: 100px;"><a class="gal_title" style="font-size: 11px;" href="/profile/User00">User00</a><br />
                    <a class=link3 href="/profile/User00"><img alt="User00's profile" style="border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;" width="90" height="90" src="/img/unknown.jpg"><img class="uonline" src="/img/online.png" title="User00 is online!"></a><div class="opt" style="clear: left;  width: 80%;"><div class="random icon"></div><div class="country iconCountry" style="background:url(/images/country/AT.gif 0 0 no-repeat;"></div><div class="sendmail"><a href="/login.php?backurl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%2fmessage.php%3fuid%0123456"><img border=0 src="/img/pm.gif"></a></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="subscribers" style="clear: left;">&lt;88 fans&gt;</div></div>
    </td>

<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size: 10px;" nowrap>
                </td>
</tr>
        
    <tr id="10180382" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="border-top: dotted 1px #000000;">
                <td width="70%">
            <img style="margin-top: -6px;" align="absmiddle" src="/img/arrow-r.gif">&nbsp;
            <a title="View Gallery 1" class="gal_title" href="/gallery.php?gid=10180382"><i><b>Gallery 1</b></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td><center>&nbsp;298&nbsp;</td>
        <td><center>
                            <img alt="Low Quality" src="/img/small_img.gif">
                    </td>
                <td nowrap><center>&nbsp;2022-02-28&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                <td colspan="3">
                                                                            <table><tr>
                            <!--<div style="float: left; width: 148px; text-align: center;">--><td width="148" align="center"><a title="View Gallery 1"  href="/photo/1986223183/"><img class="gal_thumb" alt="Free gallery 1 1 of  pics" src="https://cdnh.example.com/images/mini/111/198/1986223183.jpg?se=1646123719&ss=ae7f157355b3929e45ed7bbe9923eb1c"></a></td><!--</div>--><!--<div style="float: left; width: 148px; text-align: center;">--><td width="148" align="center"><a title="View Gallery 1"  href="/photo/1894873412/"><img class="gal_thumb" alt="Free Pics Gallery 1 2 of  pics" src="https://cdnh.example.com/images/mini/109/189/1894873412.jpg?se=1646123719&ss=5428161f964b796b070d593a1a9766e5"></a></td><!--</div>--><!--<div style="float: left; width: 148px; text-align: center;">--><td width="148" align="center"><a title="View Gallery 1"  href="/photo/98075857/"><img class="gal_thumb" alt="Free Pics Gallery 1 3 of  pics" src="https://cdnh.example.com/images/mini/108/980/98075857.jpg?se=1646123719&ss=ef8e4e29c3ffb0384f772122eb1dde73"></a></td><!--</div>--><!--<div style="float: left; width: 148px; text-align: center;">--><td width="148" align="center"><a title="View Gallery 1"  href="/photo/1957776812/"><img class="gal_thumb" alt="Free Pics Gallery 1 4 of  pics" src="https://cdnh.example.com/images/mini/111/195/1957776812.jpg?se=1646123719&ss=ece6a38a3a982156dea6ba2d56ba2c1e"></a></td><!--</div>-->                         

</tr>
</table>

</td>
<td align="center" valig="top">
            <div class="avatar" style="height: 118px; width: 100px;"><a class="gal_title" style="font-size: 11px;" href="/profile/User2">User2</a><br />
                    <a class=link3 href="/profile/User2"><img alt="User2's profile" style="border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;" width="90" height="68" src="https://cdnh.example.com/images/thumb/107/190/1904213141.jpg?se=1646122316&ss=539cad588fc95070e9f071e075c92083"></a><div class="opt" style="clear: left;  width: 80%;"><div class="random icon"></div><div class="country iconCountry" style="background:url(/images/country/GB.gif 0 0 no-repeat;"></div><div class="sendmail"><a href="/login.php?backurl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%2fmessage.php%3fuid%3d1234564"><img border=0 src="/img/pm.gif"></a></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="subscribers" style="clear: left;">&lt;645 fans&gt;</div></div>
    </td>

<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size: 10px;" nowrap>
                </td>
</tr>
        
    <tr id="10180365" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="border-top: dotted 1px #000000;">
                <td width="70%">
            <img style="margin-top: -6px;" align="absmiddle" src="/img/arrow-r.gif">&nbsp;
            <a title="View gallery 2&#039;s" class="gal_title" href="/gallery.php?gid=10180365"><i><b>gallery 2&#039;s</b></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td><center>&nbsp;9&nbsp;</td>
        <td><center>
                            <img alt="High Definition" src="/img/huge_img.gif">
                    </td>
                <td nowrap><center>&nbsp;2022-02-28&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                <td colspan="3">
                                                                            <table><tr>
                            <!--<div style="float: left; width: 148px; text-align: center;">--><td width="148" align="center"><a title="View gallery 2&#039;s"  href="/photo/1497090477/"><img class="gal_thumb" alt="Free Pics gallery 2&#039;s 1 of  pics" src="https://cdnh.example.com/images/mini/111/149/1497090477.jpg?se=1646123719&ss=8b9080bfc00940efaedb6d20802d8194"></a></td><!--</div>--><!--<div style="float: left; width: 148px; text-align: center;">--><td width="148" align="center"><a title="View gallery 2&#039;s"  href="/photo/1224351282/"><img class="gal_thumb" alt="Free Pics gallery 2&#039;s 2 of  pics" src="https://cdnh.example.com/images/mini/108/122/1224351282.jpg?se=1646123719&ss=8b1a588d762dfedd9b3255a0e80d0a1b"></a></td><!--</div>--><!--<div style="float: left; width: 148px; text-align: center;">--><td width="148" align="center"><a title="View gallery 2&#039;s"  href="/photo/1868885026/"><img class="gal_thumb" alt="Free Pics gallery 2&#039;s 3 of  pics" src="https://cdnh.example.com/images/mini/108/186/1868885026.jpg?se=1646123719&ss=d8acaa7d781a55654e685dac1db4e628"></a></td><!--</div>--><!--<div style="float: left; width: 148px; text-align: center;">--><td width="148" align="center"><a title="View gallery 2&#039;s"  href="/photo/1175638940/"><img class="gal_thumb" alt="Free Pics gallery 2&#039;s 4 of  pics" src="https://cdnh.example.com/images/mini/111/117/1175638940.jpg?se=1646123719&ss=81c93da5afd1572bc5a6c0d5f4982a8f"></a></td><!--</div>-->                            

</tr>
</table>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am hoping to use the `alt` attribute of the `img` element to identify   low and medium quality images. In the src they are referred to as "low quality" and "medium quality", but to the user they are simply "small" and "medium".
So, I begin the script with a query to select all `img` elements, then out of this selection, select only the `img` elements that possess the `alt` attribute. Finally, if the `alt` attribute matches either `low` or "medium" then hide the results by setting "display:none;".

Comment: It'd be very helpful to know what the "something" that's undefined is.

Comment: Can you add in a sample of your HTML and update your question as a [mcve] using the snippet tool `[<>]` in the edit window so we can help you better?

Comment: Also: 1) You should start using `const` and `let` for your variable declarations now. 2) You should declare your loop indexes: `for (let i = 0...`, 3) [`<center>` has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). 4) Instead of an inner loop you could probably use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: `img > center` means ["center elements that are direct children of an img element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator). Your markup has none.

Comment: @Andy So, basically my order of elements is reversed. Instead of going "img > center", I should go "center > img".

Answer (score 0):

> img > center means "[center elements that are direct children of an img element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator). Your markup has none. –

Andy nailed it. My elements were listed in the wrong order.